# visual effect of height in bitmap

Tags: graphics, bitmap

I am creating a map, i.e. bitmap where each pixel have some real value - height. I want to fill each pixel according to height if this pixel. I want to get something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Contour3D.jpg), but in 2D.

What is the function that maps height to (R,G,B) that I have such kind of pictures?

Edit: I code in python.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a hue, starting at 360° and going backwards to 0°. You haven't specified a language, but here's how to do the conversion from HSL to RGB in JavaScript, for example:

```
/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0) {
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    } else {
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

You'll want a fixed saturation of 100% and a lightness of 50%.